# how to generate a unique id in node.js for users registering a webservice?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, random, uniqueidentifier

I am building a webservice with node.js and I am registering users in my service. I am using node.js + mongodb for my db and once I create a new user I also want to create a unique id for them and send that back as a response, just like all the great services like fb that send u back the facebook id. I do not want to send back the _id from mongodb, so how do I generate a unique id for every user in node, also is it better to do it this way or just send back the mongo _id.

Comment: Why don't you want to send back the mongo _id value?

Comment: Consider a uuid. https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/uuid

Answer (score 7):

> is it better to do it this way or just send back the mongo _id

If you have to ask, it is better to just send back the mongo _id. Unless you have iron-clad reasoning behind why that simple, straightforward, make-life-easy-for-everyone technique is problematic, by all means, just send back the mongo _id.

If you decide the mongo _id is not good enough for you (probably due to FUD as opposed to any realistic reasoning), you have the following extra challenges you are adopting without any benefit:

- you have to think more carefully about your indexes
- Helper libraries functions like `findById` don't work for you anymore
- Now you have 2 huge, hard-to-eyeball IDs to deal with on every record
- helper libraries like mongoose are also going to be challenging to leverage
- You will have to be mapping back and forth between `_id` and `mySuperAwesomeExtraneousId` constantly during debugging for the entire lifetime of your app

K.I.S.S.

That said, you can always just use an additional mongo `ObjectId` as they are perfectly valid unique Ids:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb')
let mySuperAwesomeExtraneousId = new mongo.ObjectID()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use coupon-code.This is simple to use and solves most of the use cases for generation of unique ids.

https://github.com/appsattic/node-coupon-code

https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous good reasons for not sending back the _id created by Mongoose by default for example. For one, those IDs could easily be guessed by a rogue entity or hacker. And it's also never a good idea to expose your database ids anyway.

For an app that relies solely on a unique ID for a password-less account access, generating a highly unique hash id may be the best option. The perfect node module for that is [hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.node.js)

You may also give crypto a try:

```
require('crypto').randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) {
  var token = buf.toString('hex');
});
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use http://mongoosejs.com as an abstraction layer to MongoDB. It will ensure that you always have the _id available. It also will manage many other things, such as validation, connections, etc.

Pros: It is simpler to use than raw drivers, while at the same time maintaining all the power of a raw MongoDB driver. You will be up and running in about 20 minutes after visiting the mongoose website. Its one of the few times you don't trade off power for simplicity. It is a thin abstraction layer, you will have a net performance gain in code by having this single, robust layer in place then by trying to re-invent the wheel on every single part of your code that needs to access the DB. It supports every single MongoDB feature. It provides validation. It provides a simple interface to managing indexes. It automatically creates databases and collections. Built by the same guys that made ExpressJS, Socket.IO and Mocha for node.js. The list goes on.

Cons: Does not support multiple MongoDB connections. This is usually not a problem though because you will most likely use MongoDB's sharding features before you need to create multiple connections to multiple MongoDB clusters. It has a silly name.

We have been using Mongoose in production environments for quite sometime. If you want to see it in action, look at ZingProject.com. Its entirely node.js + mongoose over MongoDB. Its lightning fast.